# Angularjs Class Confirm button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a "confirm" button for users of my website to see when they click on a button, and I am using an angularJS class. My code is as follows:

```
class TodosListCtrl {
  constructor($scope, $window){
    $scope.viewModel(this);
    this.$scope = $scope;
  }
//... a bunch of functions
  Clear(){
    var delete = this.$scope.confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the text?");
    if(delete){
      //delete stuff
  }
}
```

But every time I click on the button that calls the "Clear()" function, I get the error

```
"this.$scope.confirm is not a function at TodosListCtrl.Clear"
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can fix this?

Comment: I think you just need to take `this.$scope` off of `this.$scope.confirm`

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I didn't realize it was that simple.

Comment: No problem, I like it when they're that simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take `this.$scope` off of `this.$scope.confirm`:

```
class TodosListCtrl {
  constructor($scope, $window){
    $scope.viewModel(this);
    this.$scope = $scope;
  }
//... a bunch of functions
  Clear(){
    var delete = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the text?");
    if(delete){
      //delete stuff
  }
}
```